# What is a good estimate for this log sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, asymptotics, approximation

Given $n\gg0$ what is a good estimate for 
$$\sum_{i=1}^K\log\Big(\frac{n}{3^i}\Big)?$$

I am particularly interested in case of $K=O(1)$ and $K=O((\log n)^c)$ at a fixed $c>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum is $\sum_i(\log n-i\log 3)=K\log n-\frac{K(K+1)}{2}\log 3$.